# How to substitute one file path for another everywhere for my profile

Tags: bash, alias

I am using some software on a shared Linux virtual machine, and I need to create my own version of one of the software's executable files. Let's say the executable file in question is here:

```bash
$SOFTWAREDIR/bin/the_file
```

All throughout the software's scripts are calls to `$SOFTWAREDIR/bin/the_file`.

I would like it if, when I ran the software, every script that called `$SOFTWAREDIR/bin/the_file` would call my own edited version of that executable file (`my/own/path/the_edited_file`) instead.

If it were just me using the software, and if there weren't a jillion different scripts calling `the_file`, I'd try just editing the software with find-and-replace, substituting `my/own/path/the_edited_file` wherever I found a call to `$SOFTWAREDIR/bin/the_file`. However, I can see that this would be tedious, impractical, and stuff up the software for everyone else - so I shan't do that :-) I only want the substitution to occur for my user profile.

Is there a way I can achieve this by e.g. appending something to `~/.bashrc`?

I have tried adding an alias to `~/.bashrc` like this:

```bash
alias $SOFTWAREDIR/bin/the_file = my/own/path/the_edited_file
```

but the `/` character isn't allowed.

I imagine this has been asked before in a more coherent way somewhere, using words I don't yet understand - please do link me to other answers if they exist.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is there any reason why you can't simply redefine the environment variable `$SOFTWAREDIR` to point to your own implementation's `bin` directory? As in adding `export SOFTWAREDIR=my/own/path` to your `.bashrc`? You would just need to move your `the_file` to a subdirectory `bin` under `my/own/path` to make it a seamless drop-in.

Comment: Using this method you'd probably have to symlink any other executables in the $SOFTWAREDIR/bin directory in your bin directory.
But I'd suspect that the $SOFTWAREDIR is used for more the just finding executables.
unshare may be able to do what you want, but I've never tried something like this with it.